# Function call on ngClass not working

Tags: function, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, ionic2

I have a problem with a ngClass and a function with building an app with Ionic 2 and Firebase.
The function does work, but the value of the function does not come in the HTML code. I have used this as an example: https://codepen.io/andre13/pen/oecgi.

The html and the call for the function looks like this:

```
<button  ion-button class="chatbutton" [ngClass]="compareUser(user.$key)"
(click)="gotoDoctorChat(user.$key)" >{{user.naam}} </button>
```

The function looks like this:

```
  compareUser(uid){
this.angFire.database.object('/users/' + uid +'/'+ this.coach1+'red').subscribe(snapshot=>{
  console.log("snapshot.tostring = " + snapshot.$value);
  if(snapshot.$value === '0'){
    return 'unread';
  }else{
    return null;
  }
})
```

};

The CSS looks like this:

```
.unread{
    background-color: red!important;
}
```

Please ask if something is not clear.

Comment: It will be good if you can try provide a jsfiddle/codepen for your issue. it wil help us to find the cause.

Answer (score 0):

Try enclosed by single quote (') like this

```
return "'unread'";
```

and also make sure you have imported the correct module in the main component

```
import { NgClass } from '@angular/common';
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason is because function `compareUser` always returns **undefined** *before* the internal function call is resolved.

You can test this with:

```
console.log(compareUser(aUID));
```

Difficult to suggest an alternative without knowing more of your logic/requirements.